# A curious case of character encoding, PHP to MySQL and back

Tags: php, mysql, database, encoding, character

I have been stumped by an issue. It seems that most of the tricks that I have tried simply do not work. An overview of the problem is as follow:

1. Create table, collation set to utf8_unicode_ci. Same for columns.
2. Page where form is located in has a character encoding of UTF-8 (in the `<meta>` tag). Form is set to accept character set of UTF-8 (`<form action="execute.php" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">`)
3. Execute.php sanitizies form input using `htmlspecialchars(@trim($str), ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");` and also runs `mysql_real_escape_string($str);`. Declare database connection should be encoded in UTF-8 (`mysql_set_charset('utf-8');`). Insert values into db. If I halt the database insert and echo the query, I get normal looking output.
4. Now the fun begins. MySQL rows display odd characters, e.g. ß turning into ÃŸ.
5. If I retrieve the database data and present it on a page with UTF-8 encoding, the characters look jumbled (ÃŸ), too. However, when I change the page encoding to Western ISO, the character display just fine - ß.

I am suspecting that there is a problem when the form submits the data to the database... but I can't pinpoint where exactly went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things

1. Do not run your posted data through `htmlspecialchars` or any sanitation.  Validate input, but store it as-is if it's valid.
2. Sanitize output if needed, e.g. with `htmlspecialchars`.
3. Be sure to only use binary-safe functions on UTF8 strings.  Unlikely you'll run into this with modern PHP but it's possible.
4. Stop using the deprecated mysql library and switch to mysqli (easy) or PDO.
5. `SET NAMES utf8` after you initialized your database connection with mysqli.
6. Make sure your PHP file (or any used) are saved as UTF8.
7. Set your response header to UTF8: `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` You can do this from anywhere in your code if you're using output buffering.
8. Add `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` to page `<head>`.

Comment: 1. I wish I could, but I'm working on an application that had considerable work done in it... and I can't switch over to mysqli as easily as I want to.

2. I will avoid using `htmlspecialchars`. What abour `stripslashes`?

3. Shouldn't it be `SET NAMES utf8`?

4. Where should the response header be? I have placed one in exec.php, not sure if that's the right place to go.

Comment: Okay, it turns out that `mysql_query(SET NAMES utf8)` worked like a charm. Funny that `mysql_set_charset('utf-8')` didn't work :/ Thanks for your help Matt :)

Comment: @teddyrised It's ok to use htmlspecialchars, but only use it for HTML output, not changing input.  Switching to mysqli isn't a deal-breaker.  See my edits for answers to the rest.

Comment: Is there any difference if I use the new HTML5 charset declaration, i.e. `<meta charset="utf-8" />`? I'm looking into mysqli now... since the charset which bit me hard in the behind is now gone :)

Comment: No difference, use whichever meta tag is appropriate for your content. The `header()` call plus `<meta>` should make sure no browser interprets the page as anything but utf8.

Comment: And I have figured out... `mysql_set_charset('utf8');` is the right syntax (i.e. without the dash between utf and 8)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try without the htmlspecialchars() ?

Answer (score 0):

You need the character set of the database table and columns set to UTF-8 as well. Collation only deals with how data will be sorted/compared not how it is encoded.